# Сравнение многомерного списка на уникальность по заданным значениям

Tags: python, список, сравнение

Есть многомерный список примерно в 20К строк.

Значения `КОД, ЦЕНА, НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ, КАРТИНКА`:

```
list_ = [[1, 10.00, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'], [1, 11.00, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'], [2, 20.00, 'яблоко', None], [2, 25.00, 'яблоко', 'путь к jpg'], [3, 25.00, 'Банан', 'путь к jpg'], [4, 25.00, 'Персик', None]
```

Не получается сравнить список на уникальность по коду и мин. цене.

Результат должен быть:

```
list_2 = [[1, 10.00, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'], [2, 20.00, 'яблуко', None], [3, 25.00, 'Банан', 'путь к jpg'], [4, 25.00, 'Персик', None]
```

`unique` , и `set` результат не дали.

Кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Что значит "сравнить на уникальность"? для меня вот не очевидно, почему у вас во втором списке остался первый элемент из первого списка, а не второй (с помидорами).

Comment: по какому алгоритму выбирается уникальная запись - по минимальной цене или по первому вхождению?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd #  pip install pandas
```

создаем Pandas DataFrame из списка записей:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_, columns=["ID", "price", "name", "path"])
```

получилось:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
   ID  price     name        path
0   1   10.0  помидор  путь к jpg
1   1   11.0  помидор  путь к jpg
2   2   20.0   яблоко        None
3   2   25.0   яблоко  путь к jpg
4   3   25.0    Банан  путь к jpg
5   4   25.0   Персик        None
```

убираем дубликаты, оставляя записи с минимальной ценой:

```
res = df.sort_values("price").drop_duplicates(subset=["ID"])
```

результат:

```
In [95]: res
Out[95]:
   ID  price     name        path
0   1   10.0  помидор  путь к jpg
2   2   20.0   яблоко        None
4   3   25.0    Банан  путь к jpg
5   4   25.0   Персик        None
```

результат в виде списка:

```
res_list = res.to_numpy().tolist()

In [97]: res_list
Out[97]:
[[1, 10.0, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'],
 [2, 20.0, 'яблоко', None],
 [3, 25.0, 'Банан', 'путь к jpg'],
 [4, 25.0, 'Персик', None]]
```

---

**UPD:**

> В колонке "Прайс" есть цены в виде строки, '25.00'. как на лету их
> преобразовать в float.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_, columns=["ID", "price", "name", "path"])

df["price"] = pd.to_numeric(df["price"], errors="coerce")

res = df.sort_values("price").drop_duplicates(subset=["ID"])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это то что нужно.

Comment: автор вроде нигде не отмечал, что исходный список отсортирован )

Comment: @strawdog, именно поэтому я сортирую его по цене - `df.sort_values("price")`, а `.drop_duplicates()` сам оставит только первые вхождения по `ID`)

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но есть еще один вопрос.  В колонке "Прайс" есть цены в виде строки, '25.00'  list_ = [[1, 10.00, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'], [1, 11.00, 'помидор', 'путь к jpg'], [2, 20.00, 'яблоко', None], [2, '25.00', 'яблоко', 'путь к jpg'], [3, 25.00, 'Банан', 'путь к jpg'], [4, 25.00, 'Персик', None]. Как на лету их преобразовать в float. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Большое спасибо за реакцию. Все получилось

Comment: Появился еще один вопрос) Возможно ли вовремя сортировки или перед сортировкой дубликаты  скажем ID 1  продублировли 'path'  вместо None. Заранее спасибо за любой ответ

Comment: @SergeyBulavka, я думаю лучше задать (открыть) новый вопрос с небольшим примером входных данных и примером того, что вы хотите получить на выходе